# Curl PHP cannot display amazon

Tags: php, curl

I am using the following code and am not able to display amazon.com using php and curl. Im using curl_error and getting no errors, so I'm not sure what im doing wrong

```
<?php 

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.amazon.com');

curl_exec($curl);

curl_close ($curl);
```

I'm doing this on local host

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What exactly is not working with the given code?

Comment: im just trying to scrape amazon, this exact code worked just the day before, with the ssl_verifypeer. im new to this and do not understand the importance of debugging, but according to a later post, there is a bug that can be fixed by using curlopt_encoding

Answer (score 5):

just display amazon then use this

```
echo file_get_contents("https://www.amazon.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

$result is an array. You can get for example the body of the request by using:

```
$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $result['header'] = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
        $result['body'] = substr( $response, $header_size );
        $result['http_code'] = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $result['last_url'] = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

echo $result['body'];
```

For more information: http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-exec.php

Answer (score 1):

when debugging curl code, use CURLOPT_VERBOSE, and post the CURLOPT_VERBOSE log when asking for help. also when debugging, do not ignore the return values of curl_setopt, because it returns bool(false) if there was an error, and if there was an error, that error would probably explain why the code isn't working. also do not ignore the return value of curl_exec, because it returns bool(false) if there was an error, which goes unnoticed if you ignore the return value (and your code does)

here is a version of your code that doesn't ignore any errors and enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE logging, it should reveal where your code fails:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
if (! is_resource($curl)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('curl_init() failed!');
}
ecurl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.amazon.com');
ecurl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$curlstderr = etmpfile();
$curlstdout = etmpfile();
ecurl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curlstderr);
ecurl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $curlstdout);
if (true !== curl_exec($curl)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException("curl_exec failed! " . curl_errno($curl) . ": " . curl_error($curl));
}
rewind($curlstderr); // https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268
rewind($curlstdout); // https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268
$verbose = stream_get_contents($curlstderr);
$output = stream_get_contents($curlstdout);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($curlstderr);
fclose($curlstdout);
var_dump($verbose, $output);

function ecurl_setopt ( /*resource*/$ch, int $option , /*mixed*/ $value): bool
{
    $ret = curl_setopt($ch, $option, $value);
    if ($ret !== true) {
        // option should be obvious by stack trace
        throw new RuntimeException('curl_setopt() failed. curl_errno: ' . return_var_dump(curl_errno($ch)) . '. curl_error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    return true;
}

function etmpfile()
{
    $ret = tmpfile();
    if (false === $ret) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('tmpfile() failed!');
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

also, it appears that https://www.amazon.com has a bug, see [is it a bug to send response gzip-compressed to clients that doesn't specify Accept-Encoding: gzip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130908/is-it-a-bug-to-send-response-gzip-compressed-to-clients-that-doesnt-specify-acc)

- in any case, to make curl automatically decompress the gzip-compressed response from amazon, add `ecurl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'');` , that tells libcurl to add the `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` header, and automatically decompress the result.