# is it a bug to send response gzip-compressed to clients that doesn't specify Accept-Encoding: gzip?

Tags: http

is it a bug in the server if it sends content gzip-compressed to clients that did not specify `Accept-Encoding: gzip` ? is it breaking the http specs? or is it legal?

i'm curious because https://www.amazon.com always sends content gzip-compressed, regardless of the Accept-Encoding header, as a simple test to confirm:

```
$ curl https://www.amazon.com
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.

$ curl https://www.amazon.com -I
HTTP/2 405
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
server: Server
date: Sat, 03 Nov 2018 11:27:35 GMT
set-cookie: skin=noskin; path=/; domain=.amazon.com
strict-transport-security: max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload
x-amz-id-1: 2M3HZHHA9J21D3MTHH4K
allow: POST, GET
vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent,X-Amazon-CDN-Cache
content-encoding: gzip
x-amz-rid: 2M3HZHHA9J21D3MTHH4K
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 1cc4305a3ce000ca199328864ca1c98e.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: OKz61IdKmCBfC97pPg-zmDhQnJzK3THXL2iYwegU5EtDaRf6yjBGzw==
```

- curl complains that it's recieving binary data here because it's not responding with HTML, but gzip-compressed html, which is binary data. to actually see the html, add the `--compressed` argument, which tells curl to add the header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` and automatically decompress the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A request without an Accept-Encoding header field implies that the user agent has no preferences regarding content-codings. Although this allows the server to use any content-coding in a response, it does not imply that the user agent will be able to correctly process all encodings.

-- https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.5.3.4.p.4

Comment: guess that means `no`, the specs allow this behavior ^^ the same document also states `An "identity" token is used as a synonym for "no encoding"`  - and indeed, `curl -H "Accept-Encoding: identity" https://www.amazon.com` turns off compression from amazon.com